# Неверный путь при клонировании проекта

Tags: git, git-clone, clone

пытаюсь клонировать себе свой же проект, пишу когда на ноутбуке(Linux) когда на компе(Windows), выдает ошибку когда клонирую на компьютер, плохо разбираюсь, спасибо за помощь
Вот ошибка

```
Cloning into 'C:\Users\dimma\Desktop\All_Tasks_Progects'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2730, done.        
remote: Total 2730 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 2730        
Receiving objects: 100% (2730/2730), 125.69 MiB | 8.60 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1094/1094), done.
error: invalid path 'C/The C Programming Language/AnotherTasks/fopen\getc\fillbuf/_FILE.h'
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

---

ссылка на проект если нужно: https://github.com/dimmarvel/All_Tasks_Progects

Comment: а вот как Вам удалось добавить файл "fopen\getc\fillbuf/_FILE.h" (тут слеши кривые).  Или это у файла такое имя?

Comment: в том то и дело я не сам не знаю что это и как попало сюда)

Comment: перейдите на линукс, найдите этот файл и удалите, потом коммит и пуш

Comment: @KoVadim, можно же и прямо в веб-морде github.com и переименовать и удалить.

Comment: возможно, главное, что бы гитхаб справился.